# Can't connect to PostgreSQL with JDBC driver

Tags: java, mysql, spring, postgresql, jdbc

I have my Spring MVC app.

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<bean id="dataSource"    class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource">
<property name="driverClassName" value="org.postgresql.Driver"/>
<property name="url" value="jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dailyjob"/>
<property name="username" value="root"/>
<property name="password" value="root"/>
</bean>
```

When my app is trying to connect to the database, I get the exception

> Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ?????: ????????????
>   "root" ?? ?????? ???????? ??????????? (?? ??????)     at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.doAuthentication(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:398)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.core.v3.ConnectionFactoryImpl.openConnectionImpl(ConnectionFactoryImpl.java:173)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.core.ConnectionFactory.openConnection(ConnectionFactory.java:64)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Connection.(AbstractJdbc2Connection.java:136)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc3.AbstractJdbc3Connection.(AbstractJdbc3Connection.java:29)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc3g.AbstractJdbc3gConnection.(AbstractJdbc3gConnection.java:21)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc4.AbstractJdbc4Connection.(AbstractJdbc4Connection.java:31)
>     at
>   org.postgresql.jdbc4.Jdbc4Connection.(Jdbc4Connection.java:24)
>     at org.postgresql.Driver.makeConnection(Driver.java:393)    at
>   org.postgresql.Driver.connect(Driver.java:267)    at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)  at
>   java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)  at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriverManager(DriverManagerDataSource.java:173)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:164)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnectionFromDriver(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:153)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractDriverBasedDataSource.java:119)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.doGetConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:111)
>     at
>   org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceUtils.getConnection(DataSourceUtils.java:77)
>     ... 46 more

If I'm trying to connect to mysql with

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DriverManagerDataSource"
p:driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
p:url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/dailyjob"
p:username="root"
p:password="root" />
```

everything is OK!

My app has jdbc drivres for both (mysql and postgres).

Comment: Please post what is the exact exception you are getting?

Comment: You haven't shown us the error message that comes with the exception (seems the stacktrace is cut off somehow). But based on the `doAuthentication()` method in the stacktrace I would assume that it is: "password authentication failed for user 'root'". Do you **really** have a _database_ user named `root`. The superuser in Postgres is usually named `postgres` during installation. Can you connect using `root/root` using `psql` (or any other SQL Client). The fact that you can connect using MySQL says nothing. MySQL and Postgres do not share the same user accounts.

Comment: You say you can connect to mysql using the postgresql driver? Seems unlikely!

Comment: **user2065083**
I've got (in NetBEans output) exactly this exception: **org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ?????: ???????????? "root" ?? ?????? ???????? ??????????? (?? ??????)** - with question signs



**harmic**
I've corrected the second xml, it was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

I am also uses postgresql with Java earlier I also facing the same problem,

I work around and found the solution, 
could you please try with adding below statement to bean "dataSource"

`<property name="defaultAutoCommit" value="false"/>`